# Unable to anonymously pull images from okd/openshift-origin docker registry using docker pull

Tags: docker, openshift, openshift-origin, okd

Using okd/openshift-origin 3.11 (and previous versions) we've been unable to get anonymous image pulls working.

We've tried adding various groups to the `registry-viewer` role as indicated by the instructions from the [merge request where the feature was added](https://github.com/openshift/origin/pull/9887).

We've tried:

```
oc policy add-role-to-user registry-viewer system:anonymous -n <project>
oc policy add-role-to-user registry-viewer system:unauthenticated -n <project>
```

When viewing the registry in the GUI the access policy shows *Anonymous: Allow all unauthenticated users to pull images*

Yet this is the result when trying to pull:

```
docker pull docker-registry-default.$cluster/$project/$image:latest
Error response from daemon: Get https://docker-registry-default.$cluster/v2/$project/$image/manifests/latest: unauthorized: authentication required
```

What are we missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a `$HOME/.docker/config.json` credential file on the client machine, could you try whether you can pull the image after removing the credential file (or backup) ?
Because `docker pull` is using `$HOME/.docker/config.json` by default, it can cause unexpected authorization trouble like this by authenticating as the credential file. As removing docker credential file(config.json) you can verify whether `docker pull` is conducted by `unauthenticated`.